# handle request raised JsonParseException

Tags: java, json, exception

I am posting to an endpoint and passing a Json in it.

```
@POST("/start")
    @PermitAll
    public String Connect(Map form) 
    {
        String stack_callback;
        String wfid;
        String ch_id;
        try {
            elem1 = form.get("elem1").toString();
            elem2 = form.get("elem2").toString();
            elem3 = form.get("elem3").toString();
            elem4 = form.get("elem4").toString();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return "error";
        }

        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4);

        new Thread(threadStart).start();
        return "Start the thread";
    }
```

Now if I send POST with e.g. a key with no value (like following), I am getting "`request raised JsonParseException`":

```
{
    "elem1": "val1",
    "elem2": "val2",
    "elem3": ,
    "elem4": "val4"
}
```

How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 7 or later:

```
catch (NullPointerException | JsonParseException e) {
    // log e, handle the exception
}
```

If you are using Java 6 or earlier:

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // log e, handle null pointer
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    // log e, handle key with no value
}
```

You could also have the `Connect` method `throw` a `JsonParseException`:

```
public String Connect(Map form) throws JsonParseException {
    // ...
}
```

But `Connect` seems to be an entry point for a POST request coming from a web framework.  Whoever is calling `Connect` may not be suited to handle your problem with parsing JSON, so you probably will want to go with catching the exception in your code.